# Create 2 Meteor.js Collections from the same MongoDB Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Is it possible to have both a `Meteor.Collection` and a `Meteor.SmartCollection` created from the same mongodb collection? Was hoping to use `.observeChanges()` available in `Meteor.Collection`, and `sort`/`limit` operators available in `Meteor.SmartCollection`.

**myCollection.js**

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.SmartCollection('myCollection');
MyCollection2 = new Meteor.Collection('myCollection')
```

**Error**

```
/Users/username/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
 Error: A method named '/myCollection/insert' is already defined
     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1210
     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:87)
     at _.extend.methods (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1208)
     at Meteor.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:673)
     at new Meteor.Collection (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:176)
     at app/collections/myCollection.js:2:9
     at app/collections/myCollection.js:4:3
     at /Users/username/Dropbox/Projects/myApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/username/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

Comment: I think the functionality of Smart Collections is now merged in regular Meteor Collections, since Meteor 0.7. Isn't that so?

Comment: @HubertOG i think the regular meteor collection cannot yet handle sort/limit

Comment: @Nyxynyx Yes it can, it just uses the old poll-and-diff algorithm rather than oplog for anything other than equality checks on scalars. They'll be releasing updates for other types of queries with oplog as they ensure that they are 100% compatible with MongoDB's API. By 1.0 there should be absolutely no reason to use Smart Collections; if your site won't be going live in the next month or so, you might as well just use the native Collections. If you're using both Collections and SmartCollections together, you're probably not getting the full benefit of oplog anyway.

Comment: @Cuberto Is it possible to increase the polling frequency to like 1 second with the native Collections? There's data being written from an external app and 10 sec is too long to wait for data to be refreshed when my query uses sort & limit.

Comment: Seems hardcoded `var intervalHandle = Meteor.setInterval(
      _.bind(self._ensurePollIsScheduled, self), 10 * 1000);`